# Member assignment in a const function

Tags: c++, function, constants, variable-assignment, member

I have a class member *myMember* that is a *myType* pointer. I want to assign this member in a function that is declared as const. I'm doing as follows:

```
void func() const
{
     ...
     const_cast<myType*>(myMember) = new myType();
     ...
}
```

Doing this works fine in VC++, but GCC gives an error with the message "lvalue required as left operand of assignment".

Making the member *mutable* allow me to simply remove the const_cast and assign the value. However, I'm not entirely sure that that comes with other side-effects.

Can I assign my member without having to make the member mutable? How? Are there any side-effects in making members mutable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code wont actually work in VC++ - you're not updating the value (or at least it shouldnt), hence the warning from GCC. Correct code is

```
const_cast<myType*&>(myMember) = new myType();
```

or [from other response, thanks :P]:

```
const_cast<ThisType*>(this)->myMember = new myType();
```

Making it mutable effectively means you get implicit `const_cast`s in `const` member functions, which is generally what you should be steering towards when you find yourself doing loads of `const_cast`s on `this`. There are no 'side-effects to using mutable' other than that.

As you can see from the vehement debates circling this question, willy-nilly usage of `mutable` and lots of `const_cast`s can definitely be symptoms of bad smells in your code. From a conceptual point of view, casting away constness or using `mutable` can have much larger implications. In some cases, the correct thing to do may be to change the method to non-const, i.e., own up to the fact that it is modifying state.

It all depends on how much const-correctness matters in your context - you dont want to end up just sprinking `mutable` around like pixie dust to make stuff work, but `mutable` is intended for usage if the member isnt part of the observable state of the object. The most stringent view of const-correctness would hold that not a single bit of the object's state can be modified (e.g., this might be critical if you're instance is in ROM...) - in those cases you dont want any constness to be lost. In other cases, you might have some external state stored somewhere ouside of the object - e.g., a thread-specific cache which also needs to be considered when deciding if it is appropriate.

Comment: I think while this works it is possibly the worst solution. It completely hides what happens (changing an internal state of an immutable instance) in a const-cast in the member function. "mutable" would be clearer (or using interfaces).

Comment: casting away constness leads to undefined behavior. Use at your own risk. A better solution would be to make the method non const.

Comment: @LokiAstari No, casting away `const`ness does not invoke UB - unless the underlying referred object was originally declared `const`, a misstep that IMO makes the programmer deserving of UB. For the rest, with reference to objects that were not `const`-qualified at their declaration, casting away `const`ness is _perfectly_ well-defined. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3485333/2757035

Comment: @underscore_d Nope.  I never said it was UB. I said it leads to UB. If you cast away constness in a const method you are likely to cause UB. If you add constness in a non cost method nothing bad will happen. I stand by my original statement. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4042626/14065 modifying any object where the const has been cast away **"may"** cause UB. It may not but a conforming implementation may (which allows for some optimizations). Modifying an object that was actually const is definitely UB.

Comment: @LokiAstari Your use of "leads to" is inadvisable - you meant 'makes the programmer likely to do something daft', but most people will read this as 'directly causes'. Anyway, both our links have quotes suggesting the result is defined, so long as the original object was not declared `const`. Your link's opening quote seems to contradict this - but then _links to the same example I'm citing_. I think this is another bit of poor wording by the Standard but, as it goes on to quote a defined example of a `const_cast`ed ptr modifying a non-`const` object, must keep betting on my 1st interpretation.

Comment: @underscore_d I disagree. You are basically saying that under some circumstances that casting away constness is fine. Though technically correct the point is obtuse (when there is a write involved) and thus I disagree and think the code is **fundamentally broken**. Inside a method there is no way to tell if the original object was const or not and thus you are basically playing Russian roulette. Code that is brittle and depends on curcumstances to be either UB or not is broken. So yes though I don't say it explicitly I am hinting very heavily that it is going to blow up in your face.

Comment: The though that if I have a const object and call a const method that my code will exhibit UB should not happen. I probably did not write the method in question (I use a lot of other people's code). So having the author create classes that can blow up my code when I call it correctly is broken behavior. Thus my original statement stands.

Answer (score 17):

This scenario -- an encapsulated internal state change that does not impact external state (e.g. caching results) -- is exactly what the `mutable` keyword is for.

Comment: Mutable is not good way if you want get write access to member in only one const-method.

Comment: The externally observable state of the object must not change when writing to a mutable object.  Making a member mutable just to circumvent an error in a const function is not legitimate if the change is externally visible, and may lead to undefined behavior.  Legitimate uses of mutable include caching, where for example the same call twice returns the same result, but faster.

Answer (score 6):

`const_cast` is nearly always a sign of design failure.  In your example, either `func()` should not be `const`, or `myMember` should be `mutable`.

A caller of `func()` will expect her object not to change; but this means "not to change in a way she can notice"; this is, not to change its external state.  If changing `myMember` does not change the object external state, that is what the `mutable` keyword is for; otherwise, `func()` should not be `const`, because you would be betraying your function guarantees.

Remember that `mutable` is not a mechanism to circunvent const-correctness; it is a mechanism to improve it.

Comment: ^ Yes, and sometimes the failure is in a library you're using! I use one that takes a pointer-to-non-`const` but (and I check this regularly:) doesn't mutate the object. Secure in this knowledge, so I can pass any `Obj const &` (including a temporary) to said library, I wrap it in a function that does a `const_cast<Obj *>(&constObj)`. Ugly, maybe - but truer to the reality of what actually happens to the `Obj` and lets me do better things with the library... at least until the author decides to use C++ more than C [sigh]

Comment: @underscore_d That's one of the legitimate uses of `const_cast`: dealing with imperfect C++. If I had a cent for each ponter-to-non-const that should be a pointer-to-const in the world...

Comment: @Gorpik For sure. As an aside, I wonder how many of these problems are caused by people just not adhering to `const`-correctness - and how many by people _trying to_ but not using right-to-left declaration order ;-)

Answer (score 5):

```
class Class{
int value;
void func()const{
const_cast<Class*>(this)->value=123;
}
};
```

Comment: You need cast object instead of a member.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going by Ruben's first code since it looks cleaner. If I could, I'd mark both as "answer".

Answer (score 1):

As Steve Gilham wrote, `mutable` is the correct (and short) answer to your question. I just want to give you a hint in a different direction. 
Maybe it's possible in your szenario to make use of an (or more than one) interface?
Perhaps you can grok it from the following example:

```
class IRestrictedWriter // may change only some members
{
public:
  virtual void func() = 0; 
}

class MyClass : virtual public IRestrictedWriter
{
public:
  virtual void func()
  {
    mValueToBeWrittenFromEverybody = 123; 
  }

  void otherFunctionNotAccessibleViaIRestrictedWriter()
  {
    mOtherValue1 = 123;
    mOtherValue2 = 345;
  }

  ...   
}
```

So, if you pass to some function an `IRestrictedReader *` instead of a `const MyClass *` it can call `func` and thus change `mValueToBeWrittenFromEverybody` whereas `mOtherValue1` is kind of "const".

. I find `mutable` always a bit of a hack (but use it sometimes).