# Should Mutex's lock/unlock functions be "const"?

Tags: c++, multithreading, api

I am maintaining a library that contains a Mutex class. I cannot decide if the lock() and unlock() functions exposed by this class should be const or not. I looked for similar code on the Web, and could find both implementations.

First implementation, lock() and unlock() are not const. It means someone who uses the Mutex class in a const function should put extra effort to call Mutex's functions:

```
class Mutex
{
public:
   void lock();
   void unlock();
};

class Foo
{
public:
   void getBar(Bar& bar) const
   {
      m_mutex.lock();
      bar = m_bar;
      m_mutex.unlock();
   }

private:
   // Mutable, responsability of the user (or we could use a const_cast when needed)
   mutable Mutex m_mutex;
   Bar   m_bar;
};
```

Second implementation, lock() and unlock() are const, even if that does not sound very natural (as we modify the Mutex instance), but the user does not have to bother when calling those functions in one of his const functions:

```
class Mutex
{
public:
   void lock() const;
   void unlock() const;
};

class Foo
{
public:
   void getBar(Bar& bar) const
   {
      m_mutex.lock();
      bar = m_bar;
      m_mutex.unlock();
   }

private:
   Mutex m_mutex;
   Bar   m_bar;
};
```

What solution do you prefer ? I hope your opinions will help me to take a decision.

Comment: When I have a function that takes a parameter that will be modified in such a way as in getBar, I like to call it fillBar so there is no ambiguity about what it does.

Answer (score 10):

`mutable` was made for this kind of stuff. Namely, `mutable` applies to things that don't take part in the *logical constness* of an object. (If one value is "logically constant", it means the 'primary' values are constant; the value of the object, from the outside, cannot change.)

The value of your object is *independent* from the state of the mutex (it's only an implementation detail to provide consistency, and it's state is not known outside the class), which is a good sign your mutex should be `mutable`.

---

Note, you should not go the `const_cast` route. [This leads to undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484233/const-method-that-modifies-this-without-const-cast/3485333#3485333) if you did:

```
const Foo f;

Bar b;
f.getBar(b); // takes const off of mutex, modifies (bang you're dead)
```

Comment: Does that mean that if a class has a mutable member, the compiler/linker handles it differently (i.e. unlike for "normal" const classes, its instances can't be put into a const address space)?

Comment: @Péter: Yup. §3.9.3/3: "Each non-static, non-mutable, non-reference data member of a const-qualified class object is const-qualified..." So a `mutable` member does not get a const-qualification.

Answer (score 8):

I prefer the first option of making the `Mutex` `mutable` in the client code. By this, the user of the class explictly knows that he is calling a non-const function from his const function. In fact if you see the MFC implementation of [CMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19ez063f%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) class you can see `Lock` and `Unlock` methods are non-const.

Comment: This sounds more natural to me as well. Another example is Qt QMutex implementation whose lock and unlock are not const either: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qmutex.html

Answer (score 3):

The first implementation is preferred: the const condition refers to **logical const-ness** vs. **binary const-ness**: the mutex is a helper class - it does not actually change the logical state of the client code, but changing it does change the binary state of the client code.

As such, the mutex should be made `mutable` in the client code.

The same situation arises if you are caching some costly operation results in your code: you declare the chache variable as mutable, so when computing it you don't need to throw away the `const`-ness of the class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to derive classes from the Mutex class, then it makes (some) sense to make the two functions const, then you can call it in the derived class's own const functions.

Like this:

```
class Foo : public Mutex {
public:
    void
        bar() const { lock(); doSomething(); unlock(); }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a bad example. Using inheritance to add something to a class that can trivially be added by composition is bad style IMHO.

Comment: @Martin: It's not worse than cheating with `mutable` in the encapsulation: both methods have pros and cons. In this case it all depends on the usage pattern of the Mutex class, and how it feels more natural to the programmer, IMO.