# Avoiding code duplication (const-correctness) redux

Tags: c++, constants, code-duplication, const-correctness

I was reading this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123758/how-do-i-remove-code-duplication-between-similar-const-and-non-const-member-funct) here regarding const-correctness.  The Scott Meyer solution seems like a good work-around, but what if you have a member function (which requires both a const and non-const version) that makes use of the `this` pointer.  If the member function is `const` then `this` automatically means `const this`, which can make it difficult to have a single `const` function where the bulk of the code lies.

One possible work-around that occurred to me was simply to pass a reference to `this` to the const function as a parameter, so the function can use that reference instead of directly using the `this` pointer.  But, is this safe?  It seems to be safe (if very hacky), because you're not actually using `const_cast` on a const-object.  Rather, you're simply circumventing the contract provided by the `const` member function by passing it a non-const reference of the object.

For example:

```
class Foo
{
    private:

    template <class SelfReference>    
    void f1(SelfReference& self) const
    { 
        // We now might have a non-const reference to "this", even though
        // we're in a const member function.  But is this safe???
    }

    public:    

    void f2()
    {
        f1(*this);
    }

    void f2() const
    {
        f1(*this);
    }
};
```

This seems to provide a nice way to avoid having to duplicate large quantities of code when a const and non-const version of a function is required, but is this safe?  Or does it cause undefined behavior somehow?

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484233/const-method-that-modifies-this-without-const-cast)?

Answer (score 0):

Note that even if you are in const `f1()` function and you can modify "this", `f2()` is marked as non-const, thus by calling `f2()` object may be modified. And `f1()` alone will not let you to modify "this" within itself (or any const object). You even can't call `f2()` in aid of `const Foo` object, so this doesn't bring any benefit.

In other words - in your example non-const `f1()` would be sufficient. You don't need `f1() const` or both versions here.

---

**UPDATE**
Now you won't be able to modify `self` in "const" version of `f1()` that is `void f1(const 
Foo & self) const` called from `void f2() const`.

Comment: I modified it a bit: the idea is that you have two versions of f2 (const and non-const), both of which call f1 which is `const`.  However, the non-const version of f2 passes a non-const self-reference, whereas the const version of f2 passes a const self-reference.  So the idea is that most of the logic can go in f1 to avoid duplication.

Comment: I understand that - but the idea is not actually to modify `this` from a constant member function, but just to avoid code duplication.  So if for any reason f1 has to use the `this` pointer, say to pass it to an iterator or something, then there is no need to write a separate const version of f1.

Comment: @Channel72: If you won't modify object, then `const` version of method is perfectly sufficient. You can call `const` function from non-const one. You don't ever need non-const version of function in such case, so the code won't be duplicated.