# Returning non-const reference from a const member function

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

Why does returning the reference to a pointed-to member variable work, but not the other?  I know that a `const` member function should only return `const` references, but why does that not seem true for pointers?

```
class MyClass
{
  private:
    int * a;
    int b;
  public:
    MyClass() { a = new int; }
    ~MyClass() { delete a; }

    int & geta(void) const { return *a; } // good?
    int & getb(void) const { return b; }  // obviously bad
};

int main(void)
{
  MyClass m;

  m.geta() = 5;  //works????
  m.getb() = 7;  //doesn't compile

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
int & geta(void) const { return *a; } // good?
int & getb(void) const { return b; }  // obviously bad
```

In a  const-function, every data member becomes const **in such way that it cannot be modified**. `int` becomes `const int`, `int *` becomes `int * const`, and so on.

Since the *type* of `a` in your first function becomes `int * const`, as opposed to `const int *`, so you can change the data (which is modifiable):

```
  m.geta() = 5;  //works, as the data is modifiable
```

Difference between : `const int*` and `int * const`.

- `const int*` means the pointer is **non-const**, but the data the pointer points to is **const**.
- `int * const` means the pointer is **const**, but the data the pointer points to is **non-const**.

Your second function tries to return `const int &`, since the *type* of `b` become `const int`. But you've mentioned the actual return type in your code as `int &`, so this function would **not** even compile (see [this](http://www.ideone.com/xjE8E)), irrespective of what you do in `main()`, because the return *type* doesn't match. Here is the fix:

```
 const int & getb(void) const { return b; }
```

Now it [compiles fine!](http://www.ideone.com/J2eLN).

Comment: but now the return value is like a rvalue and you can't modify or assign it! what if we want to return a non-const reference?

Comment: @Pooya: const member function cannot return non-const reference to the member data. if you want to return non-const reference to the member data, then you've to non-const version of the member function.

Comment: so how can I tell the user that this function is not modifying the instance( it was the usage of the const member function! )?

Comment: @Pooya: non-const member function can be invoked on ONLY non-const objects, whereas const member function can be invoked on const as well as non-const object but it is invoked on non-const object only if there doesn't exist a non-const member function (which can be invoked on non-const object). So what is your question? Whatever it is, can you find an answer in my comment in any way?

Comment: I was reading this:https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#return-const-ref-from-const-memfn and looks like that it is advising that `int & geta(void) const { return *a; } // good?` should not be written. Is my inference correct? I am particularly talking about the bit where it says that sometimes compiler will catch you, sometimes not.

Answer (score 7):

Because `a` becomes `int * const a;`. That is, you cannot change the value of `a` (change what it points at), just as `const` says. The const-ness of what `a` *points at* is a completely different issue.

Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484233/const-method-that-modifies-this-without-const-cast/3485333#3485333) for a thorough discussion of const and const member functions.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that.  It's the pointer that's const, not what it's pointing to...  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nawaz's answer is very good. However, the point about the compiler catching the error need not always hold. The C++ FAQ warns about it [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#return-const-ref-from-const-memfn).

> The good news is that the compiler will often catch you if you get this wrong. In particular, if you accidentally return a member of your this object by non-const reference [...] the compiler will often detect it and give you a compile-time error [...].
>
> The bad news is that the compiler won’t always catch you: there are some cases where the compiler simply won’t ever give you a compile-time error message.
>
> Translation: you need to think. If that scares you, find another line of work; “think” is not a four-letter word.