# Preferred way of conditionally initializing a const

Tags: c++11, initialization, constants

What is the preferred way to initialize a const automatic variable? I can think of several.

`if` statement(note: later I learned [this is UB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042626/const-cast-and-ub)):

```
const std::string s;
if( condition ) { const_cast<std::string&>(s) = "first"; }
else { const_cast<std::string&>(s) = "second"; }
```

`?:` operator:

```
const std::string s = ( condition ) ? "first" : second;
```

immediately invoked function expression:

```
const std::string s = [ & ] () 
    { if( condition ) return "first" else return "second" } ();
```

Comment: I don't see how you initialize `const` variable using the first method. The `std::string s` itself isn't `const` to begin with.

Comment: @raymai97 indeed. Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

C++ Core Guidelines advise to [use lambdas for complex initialization, especially of const variables](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-lambda-init).

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` statement example does not initialize any `const`, as `s` is not `const`.

Regarding other options *(this is mainly subjective)*, here are my guidelines:

- Use the `?:` *(ternary operator)* when the expression is **short** and **easy to read**. In your case, I think it would be fine.
- Use a IIFE *(immediately invoked function expression)* or refactor the initialization to a function which returns a value **when the initialization logic is long and complex** and when it would negatively impact readability of the function where the variable is initialized.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the preferred way to initialize a const automatic variable?

The preferred way is *as simple as possible*.

With a conditional statement:

```
std::string const a = condition ? "second" : "first";
```

With a function call (C++17 `constexpr` here):

```
constexpr char const* get_const(int condition) {
    switch(condition) {
    case 0: return "first";
    case 1: return "second";
    default: return "default";
    }
}
std::string const b = get_const(condition);
```

Comment: Why `switch`? Why `int`? Your `get_const` should simply take a `bool` and return via ternary.
Your `constexpr` function is valid in C++14 as well, and would be valid in C++11 if you just used the ternary operator in its body.